# Code formatting on Stack Overflow for statisticians and other non-typical programmers

Tags: support, code-formatting, help-center

I am a statistician and I'd like to submit a few programming questions to Stack Overflow, but I am in need of some help. Like many statisticians, I am somewhat familiar with R, SAS, and LaTeX, but my knowledge of other programming languages such as HTML, Java, etc. is next to nothing.

My question is this, how to I submit my questions with out annoying everyone because I copied and pasted my code without proper formatting? (And by proper formatting I am referring to how the code appears in the Stack Overflow question, not whether I used appropriate spacing to make the code easy to read). I have seen the code snippet tool in the toolbar, but I haven't the slightest idea of how to use it.

Particularly, I'd like to know how to submit questions with proper SAS and R code formatting. I assume that I am not the only non-typical programmer who might need help with this.

See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26106978/revisions for an example of my ignorance. I am not sure what I should have done differently.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: And you can ignore the snippets tool unless you want to produce a runnable HTML / CSS / Javascript sample.

Comment: You can try out how it looks in this SE question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes I have seen guides like this, but I'd like to get help specifically with submitting SAS and R code.

Comment: Why would there be a difference between formatting SAS/R code and formatting any other code? You simply need to indent each line by four spaces (which can be done by selecting it and clicking the "indent" button, or hitting CTRL-K).

Comment: There's no difference... just paste it, select it and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: The engine uses the tags to help figure out what language you are in. You can specify the language, how to do so is somewhere on meta .

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski I think you answered my question, but I added a link as an example.

Comment: You used a code snippet in your post, these are only made for HTML/CSS/JavaScript (they add a button which lets you run the snippet in the browser). For all other languages, indenting with 4 spaces (Ctrl+K) will do the trick.